# How to output an array object when the rest of its array objects are selected?

Tags: php, arrays

With my code as an example below, I'd like to know how to output PRIZE if TYPE, COLOR and SIZE is selected. (e.g.) `$type='apple', $color='green', $size='medium'` and the OUTPUT is 14. Thanks!

```
$fruits = [

    ['type' => apple, 'color' => 'green' , 'size' => 'small' , 'prize' => 10],

    ['type' => apple, 'color' => 'red' , 'size' => 'medium' , 'prize' => 12],

    ['type' => apple, 'color' => 'green' , 'size' => 'medium' , 'prize' => 14]

];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getFruitPrice($type, $color, $size) {
    for(int $i = 0; $i < count($fruits); $i++) {
      if($fruits[$i]['type'] == $type &&
         $fruits[$i]['color'] == $color &&
         $fruits[$i]['size'] == $size) {
             return $fruits[$i]['price'];
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use array_filter to filter the array.

```
$result = array_filter($fruits, function($v) use ($selected){
    return ($v['type'] == $selected['type']) && ($v['color'] == $selected['color']) && ($v['size'] == $selected['size']) ? true : false;
});
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks Kris! I will be using this on Wordpress and return the result asynchronously on a Form. By the way, I will be loading up about 40 rows of TYPE, COLOR, SIZE and PRICE. Any advice on how I could put all of those on my array? Sorry still a newbie :)